# Unable to do flow test in corda

Tags: corda

When trying to perform to perform flow test using intellij IDE V2019.2 test fails and show the following error
command line is too long. shorten command line

Then tried to change other options in shorten command line and retested.

Then it shows  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There are no CorDapps containing the package com.kba.flows on the classpath. Make sure the package name is correct and that the CorDapp is added as a gradle dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The "IllegalArgumentException" error is thrown when the CorDapps is not present in the classpath. See below -

```
when (jars.size) {
            0 -> throw IllegalArgumentException("There are no CorDapps containing the package $scanPackage on the classpath. Make sure " +
                    "the package name is correct and that the CorDapp is added as a gradle dependency.")
```

Please check if the CorDapp jar is present in the classpath.